# TextView not refresh at moment

Tags: java, android, refresh, android-edittext, textview

The situation:
I have an `AlertDialog` where inside is a `EditText` in which i save a value that i can call using `SharedPreferences`. When i open the dialog and i write in the `EditText`, the value is displayed in a `TextView`.

**The problem:**
The `TextView` change the value only if i exit from application and i re open it. How can i update the value at the moment? When i click "Ok" in the dialog i mean.

Part of Dialog code:

```
alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
        value = input.getText().toString();

        SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreference("MyKey",0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor preferencesEditor = sp.edit();
        preferencesEditor.putString("tag", value);
        preferencesEditor.commit();    
    }
});
```

and in onCreate method:

```
SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreference("MyKey",0);
String data = sp.getString("tag","");
txt.setText(data);
```

I need update after tap over "ok" of the dialog the `txt` TextView. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get value from `EditText` and set as Text to `Textview` directly like:

```
text_view.setText(edit_text.getText.toString());
```

in `Dialog Button onClick()`

Answer (score 0):

If you google something like this "TextView not updating in Android" you'll see lots of questions posted by the user's.Even I don't know why but it has happened with many developers.All you can do is follow this code, and it will work fine.

```
 runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
   @Override
   public void run() {
      TextView.setText(someValue);
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
        value = input.getText().toString();
txt.setText(value);
        SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreference("MyKey",0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor preferencesEditor = sp.edit();
        preferencesEditor.putString("tag", value);
        preferencesEditor.commit();    
    }
});
```